# Only display customers that have both types of records and only those records

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do the following in MySQL -
I have a database with Customer Orders, and I want to display ONLY the records of customers that both of two types of Orders and ONLY those two types of Orders.

Example -

```
  Orders:
    'Customer Id'   'Product'
    0001            Widget 1
    0001            Widget 2
    0001            Widget 3
    0002            Widget 2
    0002            Widget 3
    0003            Widget 1
    0004            Widget 1
    0004            Widget 3
    0004            Widget 4
    0004            Widget 5
```

I want to display only Customers that have ordered Widget 1 and Widget 3, and only those orders

Desired Results -

```
  Orders:
    'Customer Id'   'Product'
    0001            Widget 1
    0001            Widget 3
    0004            Widget 1
    0004            Widget 3
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL???

Comment: MySQL (Sorry I didn't think it would make a difference, I will update the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT custid, product FROM transactions WHERE custid IN 
(SELECT custid
FROM transactions
WHERE product in ('w1', 'w3')
GROUP BY custid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product) = 2) 
and product IN('w1', 'w3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the orders with a list of your widgets while forcing the group to have the same amounts of rows than your list.

```
SELECT
    X.*
FROM
    Orders X
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            O.`Customer Id`
        FROM
            Orders O
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 'Widget 1' Product
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Widget 3' Product
            ) P ON O.Product = P.Product
        GROUP BY
            O.`Customer Id`
        HAVING
            COUNT(P.product) = COUNT(1)
    ) M ON X.`Customer Id` = M.`Customer Id`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDERS O1, ORDERS O2
WHERE O1.customer_id = O2.customer_id
AND ( O1.Product = "Widget 1"
AND  O2.Product = "Widget 3" )
OR (O1.Product = "Widget 3"
AND  O2.Product = "Widget 1")
AND O1.customer_id NOT IN (
       SELECT customer_id
       FROM ORDERS O3, ORDERS O4
       WHERE O3.customer_id = O4.customer_id
       AND (O3.Product <> "Widget 1"
       OR O4.Product <> "Widget 3")
       OR (O3.Product <> "Widget 3"
       OR O4.Product <> "Widget 1")
)
```

please change Customer Id to customer_id, spaces in column names are not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation:

```
select o.customer_id
from orders o
group by o.customer_id
having sum( (product = 'Widget 1') ) > 0 and
       sum( (product = 'Widget 3') ) > 0 and
       sum( (product not in ('Widget 1', 'Widget 3')) );
```

I see no reason to return the products themselves, but you could add `group_concat(product)` if you really wanted.

If you want the original rows, you can use the above for filtering.  Or:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.product in ('Widget 1', 'Widget 3') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders o2
                  where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                        o2.product not in ('Widget 1', 'Widget 3')
                 );
```